# Can I only trigger jssor slider when swiping from a certain angle?

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

I am trying to use the jssor slider plugin, it works fine but I think it's too sensitive. I only want to slider works when a user swipe horizontally, but now when I swipe diagonally, it would still trigger the slider. Can I specify an angle so that I can distinguish between vertical swipe and horizontal swipe? (I have other events to be catched for vertical swipes.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see `$DragOrientation` option.

[Options - Jssor Slider](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html)

Btw, the [Slider Maker](http://www.jssor.com/slider-maker/) can help you [Generate Code](http://www.jssor.com/slider-maker/export-code.html) easily.